# I have discord.py bot and tried the new integrations (with discord_components), but it doesn't want to listen to the selection event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Here is my `color` command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def color(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "hello!",
        components=[
            Select(
                placeholder="Pick a color",
                options=[
                    SelectOption(label="Red", value="red", emoji=""),
                    SelectOption(label="Blue", value="blue", emoji="")
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
```

How do I know what the user selects ?
​
​
​
**I tried:**

```py
def on_select_option(interaction):
```

Does not work.

```py
await bot.wait_for("select_option", check=None)
```

Does not work either, even in a loop.
​
​
​
**How do I do it ?**

Comment: how do you know those events actually exist? What library are you using? `pycord`, `nextcord`...?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I'm using discord_components I said it and I don't know the events this is the 3rd tutorial that fail

Comment: do yourself a favor and stop using ``discord components`` instead switch to a fork like ``disnake, pycord or nextcord. ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed!**
The bot needs to be a `ComponentsBot`!

https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components/blob/master/examples/basic.py

```py
from discord_components import Button, Select, SelectOption, ComponentsBot


bot = ComponentsBot("!")
"""
or you can just override the methods yourself
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot("!")
DiscordComponents(bot)
"""
```